# Make a div child have parent's right end as its zero position for start?

Tags: html, css

I created a profile dialog body like this:

```
<div style="background-color: white;
            color: black;
            border-radius: 2px; 
            position: absolute; 
            top: 52px; 
            right: 10px; 
            padding: 2px">
  <div style="width: 0;
              height: 0;
              border-style: solid;
              border-width: 0 10px 15px 10px;
              border-color: transparent transparent #ffffff transparent;
              position: relative;
              top: -10px;
              right: -165px">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to place child little triangle div always 10-20px far away from right end of parent div. How I can make second little triangle div take its start position on right from the end of parent div?

Comment: Please provide us jsfiddle.

Comment: I'll consider on this for my next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the parent div's position `relative` and the child's position `absolute`
Something like this in your example:

```
<div style="background-color: black;color: black;border-radius: 2px; position: relative;  padding: 2px ; width:1000; height:1000;">
  <div style="
  position: absolute;
  width: 200;
              height: 200;
              border-style: solid;                
              border-color: transparent transparent #ffffff transparent;                  
              top: 10px;
              right: 16px;
              background-color: blue">
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The width of the inner DIV is 20px (left border + right border). Add another 2px for the border of the outer DIV and you have 22px as your zero position for the starting of the triangle.

Therefore, if you want the triangle to start 20px from the right side of the outer DIV, it is 22px + 20px:

```
right:-42px;
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/jcsx1qv3/)</kbd>

---

```css
div{position:relative;}
#one{position:absolute;top:52px;right:200px;padding:2px;background-color:white;color:black;border-radius: 2px; }
#two{width:0;height:0;top:-10px;right:-22px;
border-style:solid;
border-width:0 10px 15px 10px;
border-color: transparent transparent #ffffff transparent;
}
body{background:darkcyan;}
```

```html
<div id="one"><div id="two"></div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, I have already solved with easier solution. =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is 2 good solutions that will allow the div and its content to flow properly with other page content.

If all you need is that "triangle", use a pseudo element instead

```css
#one {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2px;
  width:200px;
  height:80px;
  padding-right: 15px;   /* make up for the triangle so inner content does not overlap */
}
#one:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 10px 15px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #f00 transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">

</div>
More content out side the `one` div
```

This one use `float`, also have it stay either at top/right or bottom/right.

```css
#one {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 2px; 
  top: 52px; 
  right: 10px; 
  padding: 2px;
  clear: both;
}
.inner {
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
}
#two {
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 10px 15px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #f00 transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="two"></div>

  Now, anything you write here, whether it is text, or another element
  <div class="inner"></div>
  the "two" div will always stay at the right top<br><br>
    
</div>
More content out side the `one` div

<br>
<br>

<div id="one">
  Now, anything you write here, whether it is text, or another element
  <div class="inner"></div>
  the "two" div will always stay at the right top<br><br>

  This one has it stay at the right bottom

  <div id="two"></div>
</div>
More content out side the `one` div
```